# Regular expression for not allowing spaces and special symbols except underscore

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a simple validation for a filename with a rule that It should not contains any spaces and special symbols except underscore.

for space I will use the re.search :

```
          word = 'some thing'
          space_checker = bool(re.search(r"\s", word))
```

And for finding the speical characters except underscore all I know is the regex pattern :

```
           words_with_underscore = ^a-zA-Z0-9_
```

How to combine both of it to make the restriction ?

Comment: Try `re.search(r'\W', a)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this: `words_with_underscore = ^a-zA-Z0-9_` is wrong. The correct regexp to match strings containing only letters, digits and underscore is: `r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$'`

You could shorten it to `r'^\w*$'` since `\w` means "word character" (ie. letter, digit or underscore):

```
word = 'some thing'
good = bool(re.search(r"^\w*$", word))
```

And then, there is nothing to combine - this regexp does not match spaces, so it will fail for `'some thing` and pass for `'some_thing'`.

Comment: perfect ! this works smooth as a silk thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Comment: FYI `[A-z]` matches more than just letters. Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). `?` and `!` are already included in `\W` so `[^?!\W]` is **strictly** equivalent to `[^\W]` that is also equivalent to `\w`, `\S` includes `[A-za-z0-9_]` so `[A-za-z0-9_\S]` <=> `\S`, your regex is equal to `\w\S\w+` and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for correcting.